# .NET Core MVC com jQuery Vertical Accordion Menu

Tags: .net, menu, .net-core, accordion

Estou usando o menu accordion vertical do jQuery do seguinte template: https://templatemag.com/demo/Dashio/ No entanto, a operação não funciona como nele. 
Clicando em um menu

```
<li> <a asp-area="" asp-controller="PaymentMethods" asp-action="Index"> List </a> </li>
```

Ele não permanece aberto e não altera a classe do link para indicar que ele foi clicado. Alguém pode me dizer o porquê?

Comment: informe o trecho de código `jQuery` que vc está utilizando

Answer (score 0):

Segue o trecho:

```
$(function() {
  $('#nav-accordion').dcAccordion({
    eventType: 'click',
    autoClose: true,
    saveState: true,
    disableLink: true,
    speed: 'slow',
    showCount: false,
    autoExpand: true,
    //        cookie: 'dcjq-accordion-1',
    classExpand: 'dcjq-current-parent'
  });
});
```